# Formatting mysql query output

Tags: mysql, sql

In my query I want to check if the users with the specified permissions exists or not. Presently I am using the below query. It will retrieve the rows of authorised users with the specified conditions.

```
select a.ixUserAuthorization from tblechecklistuserroleassignmentxref r
inner join tblechecklistuserrole u on u.ixUserRole=r.ixUserRole and u.sname='Initiator'
inner join tblechecklistuserauthorization a on a.ixUserAuthorization=r.ixUserAuthorization
and a.ixcustomer='1'and a.ixprogram='1'and a.ixworkpackage='1'and a.ixactivity='1' and a.ixUser='626e28e8-e67a-4d11-8d2c-129d0ab79e96';
```

If any rows are returned i want to display the result as true ,If no rows are returned from the above query I want to display the result as false.

How can I modify to obtain the result as true or false .

Comment: Whether count() can be used? how to count the no of rows of select query result  ?

Comment: using function mysql_num_rows() on your result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN Count(*) >= 1 THEN 'true' 
         ELSE 'false' 
       END AS Answer 
FROM   (SELECT a.ixUserAuthorization 
        FROM   tblechecklistuserroleassignmentxref r 
               INNER JOIN tblechecklistuserrole u 
                 ON u.ixUserRole = r.ixUserRole 
                    AND u.sname = 'Initiator' 
               INNER JOIN tblechecklistuserauthorization a 
                 ON a.ixUserAuthorization = r.ixUserAuthorization 
                    AND a.ixcustomer = '1' 
                    AND a.ixprogram = '1' 
                    AND a.ixworkpackage = '1' 
                    AND a.ixactivity = '1' 
                    AND a.ixUser = '626e28e8-e67a-4d11-8d2c-129d0ab79e96') a
```

Comment: I got the requied result .. just for information Can you explain why 'a' is needed at end .

Comment: Every Inner Sql need to give an alias to make it part of outer From Statement.

Answer (score 1):

use function mysql_num_rows

ex:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result))
  echo "true";
else
   echo "false";
```

where $result is the result of your query

Comment: How do you know if php is being used?